# Why is my code throwing "ImageStorageException: No loader for image data"

Tags: java, javafx

I've started a class on Java, and we've gotten to JavaFX. I'm having trouble getting an image to display. After a little debugging, I was able to narrow it down to the following exception:

> com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorageException: No loader for image data

I know the path name is correct, as that was the first error/exception I was able to fix. The current GUI shows up blank, as if I've put nothing in the scene. I can add other aspects (such as labels), but the image never loads.

```
public class Main extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {

launch(args);

}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image Belial = new Image("file:C:\\Users\\jakem\\Desktop\\D&D Stuff\\Belial.jpg");
    System.out.println("Image loaded? " + !Belial.isError());
    if (Belial.isError()) {
        System.out.println(Belial.getException());
    }
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Belial);
    HBox hbox = new HBox(imageView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Belial");

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

These are the modules I've loaded, along with adding the JavaFX library to my project library.

> --module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

I'm using Intellij.

**EDIT:** As it turns out, my image file was not actually in jpg format despite having a jpg extension. Switched to a properly formatted jpg and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually a JPEG? Just because the extension is `jpg` does not mean the file is in that format.

Comment: Slaw, you are a godsend. I tried another jpg and it worked fine. I'm curious how it got a jpg extension if it's not actually one, but for now using a separate image worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I seem to remember reading that sometimes WebP images are given a `jpg` / `jpeg` extension. Assuming that's true I don't know the reason why. But I'm glad you managed to solve the problem regardless :)

Comment: java naming conventions please